# TextView gets clipped on Samsung devices using Helvetica S font

Tags: android, fonts, textview, truncate, clipping

I've got an ordinary TextView working correctly on all phones except on certain Samsung devices (Galaxy S2 and S3 for the moment, according to user feedback) and only when using the Helvetica S font (other pre-installed Samsung fonts work correctly).

The problem is that the text gets clipped a bit on the right, instead of wrapping correctly. I still cannot post images, but the issue is the same that happens in this question: [Android text gets clipped on some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577552/android-text-gets-clipped-on-some-devices) (and with the difference that I'm not using Hindi fonts).

This is my TextView and its layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="24dp"
    android:paddingBottom="32dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/general_padding_sides"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/general_padding_sides"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/help_01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/help_text_size"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    />
```

I tried setting clipToPadding to false on the layout to see if the clipped text could be seen, but the text gets clipped the same way, and I can't make any tests in situ as I don't have any Samsung test device yet (I depend on user feedback).

The thing is I couldn't find any other reference to this problem apart from the question linked above, but if there is a bug with Helvetica S in Samsung devices, I guess someone else should have faced this problem before.

Has anyone encountered this problem? Is there any xml property that I am missing and could prevent this behavior or is this just a Samsung bug?